# Using rle with multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I want to know the run lengths where both columns are the same. For example, with the following data:

```
v1 v2
 1  1
 1  1
 1  2
 1  3
 2  3
 2  4
 2  4
```

I want something that would return (2,1,1,1,2) similar to what the rle function does for a single column. Is there a simple function that can do this (or can the rle function be used to handle this case as well)?

Answer (score 5):

We can `paste` the columns together, apply `rle` and get the `lengths`

```
rle(do.call(paste0, df1))$lengths
#[1] 2 1 1 1 2
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .N, .(v1, v2)]$N
#[1] 2 1 1 1 2
```

Or a better approach is `rleid` with `data.table`

```
setDT(df1)[, .N, rleid(v1, v2)]$N
```

Comment: just another solution similar to `paste0` : `library(tidyr);rle(unite(df1,v, 1:ncol(df1) ,sep="")$v)$lengths`

Comment: The `data.table` solution using grouping `setDT(df1)[, .N, .(v1, v2)]$N` will fail if there is another streak with the  same combination of `v1` and `v2` values in the input data. E.g. apply this on `df2 <- rbind(df1,  df1)` and you will get `4 2 2 2 4` while the correct answer would be `2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2`.

Comment: @UweBlock Yes, you are right.  So, I included the `rleid` for cases mentioned in your comment.